# Getting error error: expected primary-expression before ‘b’

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ so I am not sure what I am doing or what's wrong any help ? I am just trying to do a simple equation of motion question where I find the initial velocity of a ball that reaches a max height of 200 meters in 30 seconds. the error in the title is what I keep getting

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

 struct Ball {
     float yf;
     float v;
 };

 using namespace std;
 void velocity (Ball b)
 {
     cout<<"words"<<(b.v = (b.yf - 0.5*9.8*900)/30)<<endl; 
     return;
 }

 int main()
 {
     velocity(Ball b);
     return 0 ;
 }
```

Comment: Also the reason I wrote it this way was because I have to use structure files and then create function files and then connect them through include and run them

Comment: What do you think that `Ball b` used as an argument of `velocity` call in `main` should do?

Comment: I assumed it just got the structure features of velocity and position of the ball and insert them  in the function ? I was following an example my professor did

Comment: @AndrewBarajas Looks like you need to revise a few basic concepts, e.g. functions, variables, types, expressions etc. First chapter of your [C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Don't get left behind at this early stage, because it is going to get harder.

Answer (score 1):

The program won't do what you're actually expecting from it. You want the code to call the method that you have defined above the main function. In fact, you don't call it because of a syntactic error.

You need to create a structure instance and utilize it in the method:

```
Ball b{0.5, 0.3}; // declaring and initializing with some random nums.
velocity(b);      // using 'b' (type of Ball)
```

Comment: Ball b{0.5,0.3} is giving the values to the structure of the ball ?

Comment: @AndrewBarajas yes, this is also a valid initialization.

Comment: what is velocity (b); doing here ? sorry I know very little

Comment: @AndrewBarajas `b` is passed to `velocity()` function.

Comment: struct Ball
{
  float yf;
};
Ball b{200.0};
//using namespace std;
void velocity(b)
{
  cout << "words" << (velocity = (b.yf - 0.5 * 9.8 * 900) / 30) << endl;
  return;
}

int main ()
{
  velocity (b);
  return 0;
}

Comment: main.cpp:19:16: error: variable or field ‘velocity’ declared void
 void velocity(b)
                ^
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:27:14: error: ‘velocity’ was not declared in this scope
   velocity (b);
              ^

Comment: @AndrewBarajas `velocity` is NOT a variable. And you cannot use a function name as a variable.

Comment: ohh  right  do you have any other suggestions  or sources for my own personal studying ?

Comment: @AndrewBarajas Read the K&R ANSI C programming book to make the fundamentals strong and keep practicing!

Comment: @AndrewBarajas Read any [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for beginners. Don't start with C until you explicitly want/need to. C and C++ are two different languages. C++ is not just C with classes as many programmers use it.

Answer (score -1):

You did not declare an object of the structure you created.
and used it

Comment: I am just pointing out that they guy did not declare an object for the structure thats all

Comment: Then the code is useless in your answer – it still doesn't work.

Comment: I am new to this thanks for pointing my mistake out